# Why do I lose reputation offered as bounty on Stack Overflow, if no answers are received as a result of the bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, bounty-dialog

I asked a question few days ago on Stack Overflow, but didn't got the specific answer for considerable amount of time. So to drew more attention to my question i started a bounty of worth 50 reputation on the question.

Now the bounty is in grace period, but I read it in bounty info page that there is no refund of reputation in case no answers are received as a result of bounty. Isn't it unfair to person like me who is having less reputation on Stack Overflow to loose such reputation without any expense? I didn't got the answer I wanted and still I lose my reputation. Why there is no refund of reputation if no answers are received in bounty period?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bounties are about giving your question more attention/visibility.

It is not a guarantee that you will get an answer by simply posting a bounty on it.

Consider it like placing an ad - you have to pay for the ad, even if nothing ever comes out of it.

Comment: I thought i will get my money back, if nobody plays the game.

Comment: @DineshM - When you are in a shop and buy a game, you pay for it even if you end up not playing it.

Comment: Yup. But here i setup a game and put up a prize money to win, then nobody turned out to play. Still i lose the prize money.

Comment: @DineshM - That's your perception. You posted an ad and nobody answered it. You still pay for the ad.

Comment: Frankly, reading your question (actually a bunch of questions, which is one reason why you failed to get any good answers), there is much you could have done to improve it (examples, focusing it, explaining what you tried, what didn't work, making it a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)), which would have gotten you well into getting an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will take care about that. But this is definitely not a discussion point here. If bounty is treated as an ad by StackExchange forums then i have no choice but to accept it.

Comment: frankly, this answer and the problem is disappointing. Reputation should be about a person's "reputation" I'm no less good at asking/answering questions, no less valuable contributor to the community, if I "offer" (OFFER, not PAY) some of my points to someone for answering a question that requires an answer or a better answer. I lose reputation for nothing, for trying to help improve this Q&A site. It's just absolutely rubbish. (I just lost 100 points for requesting an answer on a question with 8 upvotes and no answers. Am very cross about losing the points)

Comment: You paid for more visibility. That greater visibility *most of the time* results in upvotes regardless of whether or not you receive an answer. Not having to pay the fee for said greater visibility and potentially upvotes would essentially make it foolish to *not* apply a bounty to every question you ask or answer because then even if you don't get an answer or the accept mark, you still likely end up with more rep in the end.